# Apple push notifications stop working after a while

Tags: iphone, ruby, sockets, apple-push-notifications, eventmachine

**FIXED!**

It turned out it was caused by our firewall which would remove idle connections from its session list after 1 hour. We increased the timeout to 24 hours and setup a eventmachine periodic timer to reconnect the connection every 23 hours. That's a workaround until eventmachine 1.0.0 hits stable which will allow us to set SO_KEEPALIVE which should resolve our issues

**The Problem was**

We are using an [eventmachine based implementation](https://gist.github.com/2966768) to push messages to the apple apns. It basically works nicely until it doesn't... :) We were trying to debug this quite hevily and now narrowed it down to something strange happening on the socket to apple after a while.

so, usually, until you send a notification to the apns server, the socket is completely quiet.
If you send a notification this is what tcpdump spits out (`sudo tcpdump -vv -i bond0 tcp port 2195`):

```
18:05:23.672477 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47828, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 3894:4331(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 893114182 2332608880>
18:05:23.776055 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 48, id 33720, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52) st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195 > my-worker-hostname.50669: ., cksum 0x7844 (correct), 2724:2724(0) ack 4331 win 159 <nop,nop,timestamp 2332623235 893114182>
```

Nothing suspicious so far imho.
However, after a while (a while being a random amount of time) our worker process starts sending packets to the apple server every 1-2 minutes even though no push notification has been triggered by us:

```
17:55:06.009741 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51807, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.54853 > st11p01st-interface002-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 0:437(437) ack 1 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 892959766 2935299208>
17:56:25.881823 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51808, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.54853 > st11p01st-interface002-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 0:437(437) ack 1 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 892979734 2935299208>
17:58:25.877756 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51809, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.54853 > st11p01st-interface002-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 0:437(437) ack 1 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 893009734 2935299208>
17:59:12.030887 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20781, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.59335 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 3749093679:3749094116(437) ack 4206642630 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 893021272 2330366860>
17:59:12.345740 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20782, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.59335 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 0:437(437) ack 1 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 893021351 2330366860>
17:59:12.977805 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20783, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.59335 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 0:437(437) ack 1 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 893021509 2330366860>
```

As soon as this starts, the push notifications don't work anymore until we restart the worker.
I'm running out of ideas here...

**UPDATE:**
after waiting another while without sending notifications and nothing happening on the socket at all I've just initiated another push, this caused the described behavior once again:

```
19:10:44.951026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47829, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894094502 2332623235>
19:10:45.361786 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47830, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894094605 2332623235>
19:10:46.185822 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47831, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894094811 2332623235>
19:10:47.837788 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47832, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894095223 2332623235>
19:10:51.133744 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47833, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894096048 2332623235>
19:10:57.725824 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47834, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894097696 2332623235>
19:11:10.913826 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47835, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 489) my-worker-hostname.50669 > st11p01st-interface013-bz.push.apple.com.2195: P 4331:4768(437) ack 2724 win 91 <nop,nop,timestamp 894100992 2332623235>
```